# EF 6 use Convert (Cast) on sql side for natural sort

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have the following issue, a column in my database of type `varchar` it consists of letters and numbers the issue is I want the results sorted naturaly.

So `1,2 .. 10, 11`

Currently I am getting `1,10,11,..,2`

On SQL side this can be done with the following query

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[ChangedAt]
  ,[ChangedBy]
  ,[CreatedAt]
  ,[CreatedBy]
  ,[RowVersion]
  ,[Name]
  ,[ERPID]
  ,[IsERPSynchronised]
  ,[Code]
FROM [Departments] order by
CASE ISNUMERIC(Code + 'e0') WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, -- letters after numbers
CASE ISNUMERIC(Code + 'e0') WHEN 1 THEN CAST(Code AS INT) ELSE 0 END,
Code
```

Which would roughly translate to the following linq query

```
IQueryable<Department> query = db.Departments;    
query = query.OrderBy(item => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(item.Code) == 1 ? 0 : 1)
.ThenBy(item => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(item.Code) == 1 ? Convert.ToDouble(item.Code) : 0);
return query.ToList();
```

Except this throws an error that Convert.ToDouble can not be converted to an SQL statement, and I can not figure out fully how to get the conversion/cast to work.

I am using Code-first

Comment: Write SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)item.Code) instead of Convert.ToDouble(item.Code)

Comment: SqlFunctions.StringConvert convert from a double to a string, but I need the string to be converted to a double

Comment: You can do one thing that implement order by clause in query.ToList().OrderBy().ThenBy(). Convert.ToDouble will work in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : 
`IQueryable<Department> query = db.Departments;

query = query.OrderBy(item => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(item.Code) == 1 ? 0 : 1)
.ThenBy(item => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(item.Code) == 1 ? (double)item.Code : 0);
return query.ToList();`

Comment: That does not work because in the model the property is of type string to also support the one that cotain letters

Comment: ok what about creating a methode that will convert string to double? for example : 

public static double? TryGetDouble(this string item)
        {
            double i;
            bool success = double.TryParse(item, out i);
            return success ? (double?)i : (double?)null;
        }   
  
then you can use is like that



query = query.OrderBy(item => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(item.Code) == 1 ? 0 : 1)
.ThenBy(item => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(item.Code) == 1 ? item.Code.TryGetDouble().value : 0);
return query.ToList();

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
int i;
var x = (from d in db.Departments
        select d).ToList()
       .OrderBy(d => int.TryParse(d.Code, out i) ? 0 : 1)
       .ThenBy(d => int.TryParse(d.Code, out i) ? int.Parse(d.Code): 99999999)
       .ThenBy(d => d.Code);
```

> **EDIT FOR SQL Server Side**

```
var x= db.Departments
   .OrderBy(d => SqlMethods.Like(d.Code, "%[^0-9]%") ? 0 : 1)
   .ThenBy(m => ("000000000000" + m.Code).Substring(12 + m.Code.Length, 12))
```

This gives the following SQL Code:

```
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = '%[^0-9]%'
DECLARE @p1 Int = 0
DECLARE @p2 Int = 1
DECLARE @p3 NVarChar(1000) = '000000000000'
DECLARE @p4 Int = 12
DECLARE @p5 Int = 12
SELECT [t0].[Code]
FROM [departments] AS [t0]
ORDER BY 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t0].[Code] LIKE @p0 THEN @p1
        ELSE @p2
     END), SUBSTRING(@p3 + [t0].[Code], @p4 + LEN([t0].[Code]) + 1, @p5)
```

Comment: I have to do the sorting SQL side because of the vast amount of recrods

Comment: @KCJHendriks See my update which does the order by Server Side